# State of the value to insert

Tags: c++, containers, language-lawyer, c++17, move-semantics

Is it possible the value passed to insert is left in a *moved from* state after move insertion if `insert` returns `false`?

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

#include <cassert>

struct less
{
    template< typename T >
    bool operator () (const std::shared_ptr<T> & lhs, const std::shared_ptr<T> & rhs) const
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

int main() {
    using key_type = int;
    using value_type = int;
    using map_type = std::map<std::shared_ptr<key_type>, std::shared_ptr<value_type>, less>;
    map_type m;
    auto p = typename map_type::value_type{std::make_shared<key_type>(1), std::make_shared<value_type>(1)};
    if (!m.insert(p).second) {
        assert(false);
    }
    assert(p.first);
    assert(p.second);
    if (m.insert(std::move(p)).second) {
        assert(false);
    }
    assert(p.first);
    assert(p.second);
}
```

Is the behavior of the last two assertion implementation defined?

Comment: why do you pass a `std::shared_pointer` on a function that you don't need to claim ownership ?

Comment: @KostasRim I wanted to pass `std::unique_ptr`, but something into `std::map` requires less strict type constraints, then `std::unique_ptr` has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [[map.modifiers/2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/map.modifiers#2) on `std::map::insert`, we have

> ```
> template<class P>  
> pair<iterator, bool> insert(P&& x);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Effects: The first form is equivalent to `return emplace(std::forward<P>(x))`.

So it's in `std::map::emplace`... from [[associative.reqmts/8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#8) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> a_­uniq.​emplace(args)
> ```
>
> Effects:  Inserts a `value_­type` object `t` constructed with `std::forward<​Args​>(​args)...` **if and only if there is no element in the container with key equivalent to the key of** `t`.

Hence, construction does **not** take place if there is already an object in the container that is associated with an equivalent key.

---

Let's verify with `<map>` from the Llvm implementation. In what follows, I've deleted some parts of the code to make it more readable. First, `std::map::insert` does this:

```
template <class _Pp, /* some SFINAE... */>
/* symbol visibility ... */
pair<iterator, bool> insert(_Pp&& __p)
    {return __tree_.__insert_unique(_VSTD::forward<_Pp>(__p));}
```

Let's go to `__tree::insert_unique`, then:

```
pair<iterator, bool> __insert_unique(__container_value_type&& __v) {
    return __emplace_unique_key_args(_NodeTypes::__get_key(__v), _VSTD::move(__v));
}
```

Still not there... but in `__tree::emplace_unique_key_args` it comes:

```
/* Template, template, template... return value... template */
__tree</* ... */>::__emplace_unique_key_args(_Key const& __k, _Args& __args)
{
    __parent_pointer __parent;
    __node_base_pointer& __child = __find_equal(__parent, __k);
    __node_pointer __r = static_cast<__node_pointer>(__child);
    bool __inserted = false;
    if (__child == nullptr)
    {
        /* Some legacy dispatch for C++03... */

        // THIS IS IT:
        __node_holder __h = __construct_node(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
        __insert_node_at(__parent, __child, static_cast<__node_base_pointer>(__h.get()));
        __r = __h.release();
        __inserted = true;
    }
    return pair<iterator, bool>(iterator(__r), __inserted);
}
```

I think we don't have to look into `__find_equal(__parent, __k)` to understand that `__child == nullptr` is the condition that triggers the actual insertion. In this branch, the call to `__construct_node` forwards the arguments, which will steal the resources managed by the `std::shared_ptr<int>` you passed in. The other branch **simply let's the arguments untouched**.

Comment: Why would this specific part of the standard not be worth relying on? I consider "if and only if" to be a pretty strong and clear requirement.

Comment: @StoryTeller Hm... good point, you're right. I'll adjust my over-cautiousness.

Comment: @lubgr: Does the "if and only if" apply to the "insert" or the "construction"? Your cautiousness *may be* justified.

Comment: @P.W Excellent catch, but wouldn't it be too weird to construct an object from `args` in order to _not_ insert it afterwards?

Comment: @lubgr: Makes sense. It is possible that the OP thought "if and only if" could apply either to "insertion" or to "construction" and asked if it was implementation defined. :-)

Comment: @P.W I strongly hope I didn't conduct my mediocre standard-reading to dig out this "if and only if" while the OP already knew and just didn't care to refer to it in the question :)

Comment: Intuitively I suspected that it can be unclear in the Standard.

Comment: BTW I meant not `template<class P>  pair<iterator, bool> insert(P&& x);` but `pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type&& x);` form.

Comment: @Orient Right, I accidentally interchanged the two overloads. Doesn't matter with respect to what the standard says ("Effects:  Inserts t if and only if there is no element in the container with key equivalent to the key of t.") though, only the detour to `emplace` isn't necessary to reach the "if and only if" part.